# How to reload only a page that is a part of a bottownavigationbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, rive

Hi i have a riveanimation that changes flower when the user has checkin, however the page of the animation would not change state once build as it is in a bottomnavigationbar. Is there anyway to reload the page to change the state of the animation. I only want to reload only one page and maintain the others.

[This is the animation picture, it should change the leaf to green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlF16.jpg)

here is my bottomnavigationbar page

```
class bottomnavbar extends StatefulWidget {
  const bottomnavbar ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _bottomnavbarState createState() => _bottomnavbarState();
}

class _bottomnavbarState extends State<bottomnavbar> {
  double screenHeight = 0;
  double screenWidth = 0;
  String currentDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now());

  Color primary = const Color(0xffeef444c);

  int currentIndex = 0;

  List<IconData> navigationIcons = [
    FontAwesomeIcons.personPraying,
    FontAwesomeIcons.leaf,
    FontAwesomeIcons.dice,
    FontAwesomeIcons.person,
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    print("Current save date is ${Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).checkDate()}");
    if( Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).checkDate() == 'not set'){
      Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).saveDatenow();

    }
    else if (Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).checkDate() != currentDate ){
      Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).overwriteSaveDate();
      Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).dailyreset();
    }
    else if (Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).checkDate() == currentDate ){

    }


    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: currentIndex,
        children: const [
           mainmenu(),
          FlowerGarden(),
           Gamespage(),
           ProfilePage(),
        ],
      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: Container(

        height: 70,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 12,
          right: 12,
          bottom: 24,
        ),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.lime,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black26,
              blurRadius: 10,
              offset: Offset(2, 2),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              for(int i = 0; i < navigationIcons.length; i++)...<Expanded>{
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        currentIndex = i;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: screenHeight,
                      width: screenWidth,
                      color: Colors.deepPurple[900],
                      child: Center(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              navigationIcons[i],
                              color: i == currentIndex ? primary : Colors.white60,
                              size: i == currentIndex ? 30 : 26,
                            ),
                            i == currentIndex ? Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                              height: 3,
                              width: 22,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
                                color: primary,
                              ),
                            ) : const SizedBox(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              }
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my riveanimation page

```
class FlowerGarden extends StatefulWidget{
  const FlowerGarden({Key? key,

}) : super(key: key);




  @override
  _SimpleFlowerGardenState createState() => _SimpleFlowerGardenState();
}
final myCoordinates = Coordinates(3.139003, 101.686855);
// Replace with your own location lat, lng.
final params = CalculationMethod.karachi.getParameters();
final prayerTimes = PrayerTimes.today(myCoordinates, params);

class _SimpleFlowerGardenState extends State<FlowerGarden>{


  SMITrigger? _SubuhEarly;
  SMITrigger? _SubuhLate;
  SMITrigger? _ZohorEarly;
  SMITrigger? _ZohorLate;
  SMITrigger? _AsarEarly;
  SMITrigger? _AsarLate;
  SMITrigger? _MaghribEarly;
  SMITrigger? _MaghribLate;
  SMITrigger? _IsyakEarly;
  SMITrigger? _IsyakLate;
  SMITrigger? _solatPerfect;
  SMITrigger? _solatImperfect;


  Artboard? _riveArtboard;

  String? message;

 

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Load the animation file from the bundle, note that you could also
    // download this. The RiveFile just expects a list of bytes.
    rootBundle.load('android/assets/lotus.riv').then(
          (data) async {
        // Load the RiveFile from the binary data.
        final file = RiveFile.import(data);

        // The artboard is the root of the animation and gets drawn in the
        // Rive widget.
        final artboard = file.mainArtboard;
        var controller =
        StateMachineController.fromArtboard(artboard, 'State Machine ',onStateChange: _onStateChange);
        if (controller != null) {
          artboard.addController(controller);
          _SubuhEarly = controller.findInput<bool>('Subuh Early') as SMITrigger;
          _SubuhLate = controller.findInput<bool>('Subuh Late') as SMITrigger;
          _ZohorEarly = controller.findInput<bool>('Zohor Early') as SMITrigger;
          _ZohorLate = controller.findInput<bool>('Zohor late') as SMITrigger;
          _AsarEarly = controller.findInput<bool>('Asar Early') as SMITrigger;
          _AsarLate = controller.findInput<bool>('Asar Late') as SMITrigger;
          _MaghribEarly = controller.findInput<bool>('Maghrib early') as SMITrigger;
          _MaghribLate = controller.findInput<bool>('Maghrib late') as SMITrigger;
          _IsyakEarly = controller.findInput<bool>('Ishak early') as SMITrigger;
          _IsyakLate = controller.findInput<bool>('Ishak late') as SMITrigger;
          _solatPerfect = controller.findInput<bool>('Solat Perfect') as SMITrigger;
          _solatImperfect = controller.findInput<bool>('Solat Imperfect') as SMITrigger;
        }
        setState(() => _riveArtboard = artboard);
      },
    );
  }

  void _onStateChange(
      String stateMachineName,
      String stateName,
      ) =>
      setState(
            () => print('State Changed in $stateMachineName to $stateName') ,
      );

  void flowercheck(){
    if (Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getSubuh() == 2){
      _solatImperfect?.fire();
    }
    else if (Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getZohor() == 2){
      _solatImperfect?.fire();
    }
    else if (Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getAsar() == 2){
      _solatImperfect?.fire();
    }
    else if (Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getMaghrib() == 2){
      _solatImperfect?.fire();
    }
    else if (Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getIsyak() == 2){
      _solatImperfect?.fire();
    }
    else {
      _solatPerfect?.fire();
    }
  }

  void leafcheck(){
    int subuh = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getSubuh();
    int zohor = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getZohor();
    int asar = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getAsar();
    int maghrib = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getMaghrib();
    int isyak = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getIsyak();
    double health = Provider.of<solatPoints>(context, listen: false).getHealth();

    switch(subuh){
      case 1:
        _SubuhEarly?.fire();
        break;
      case 2:
        _SubuhLate?.fire();
        if (health > 5) {
          Provider.of<solatPoints>(context, listen: false).decreasehealth();
        }
        break;
    }
    switch(zohor){
      case 1:
        _ZohorEarly?.fire();
        break;
      case 2:
        _ZohorLate?.fire();
        if (health > 5) {
          Provider.of<solatPoints>(context, listen: false).decreasehealth();
        }
        break;
    }
    switch(asar){
      case 1:
        _AsarEarly?.fire();
        break;
      case 2:
        _AsarLate?.fire();
        if (health > 5) {
          Provider.of<solatPoints>(context, listen: false).decreasehealth();
        }
        break;
    }
    switch(maghrib){
      case 1:
        _MaghribEarly?.fire();
        break;
      case 2:
        _MaghribLate?.fire();
        if (health > 5) {
          Provider.of<solatPoints>(context, listen: false).decreasehealth();
        }
        break;
    }
    switch(isyak){
      case 1:
        _IsyakEarly?.fire();
        break;
      case 2:
        _IsyakLate?.fire();
        if (health > 5) {
          Provider.of<solatPoints>(context, listen: false).decreasehealth();
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
      leafcheck();
    });
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
      appBar: AppBar(

        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
        title: const Text('Bunga Solat'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: _riveArtboard == null
              ? const SizedBox()
              : Stack(
            children: [
          Positioned.fill(
          child: Rive(
          artboard: _riveArtboard!,

          ),
        ),
         ]
        ),
      ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ClassProfile extends State<ClassProfile>  with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => false;




@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  if(wantKeepAlive) {
    super.build(context);
  }
    
.
.
.
.
```

first set -   with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin
then, override wantkeepalive variable
at last, defined super.build with if condition in your main widget builder function

In future if you want to persist state of your class then set wantKeepAlive => true